# Simple bouncing ball in haskell keeps bouncing higher

Tags: haskell, simulation, physics

So, I did a simple simulation of a bouncing ball to learn haskell. The ball is supposed to bounce against the image borders and to be accelerated downward by gravity.

The problem is that the ball is "magically" bouncing higher as time passes. I would expect it to keep the same maximum height instead.

I suspect there is something wrong with `bounce` and not with `move` because `bounce` "teleports" the ball back inside the frame, which is not physically accurate. I tried different way to simulate a correct behavior but could not find anything working right.

What would be a correct way to do this?

Here is the code, running on [CodeWorld](http://www.codeworld.info/):

```
main = simulationOf initial step draw

data World = Ball Point Vector

radius = 40
border = 250 - radius
g = -500

initial (x:y:vx:vy:_) = Ball (400*x  - 200, 400*y  - 200)
                             (400*vx - 200, 400*vy - 200)

step t world = bounce (move t world)

move t (Ball (x,y) (vx,vy)) = Ball (x + vx*t, y + vy*t) (vx, vy + g*t)

bounce (Ball (x,y) (vx,vy)) = Ball (nx,ny) (nvx, nvy)
  where nx  = fence (-border) border x
        ny  = fence (-border) border y
        nvx = if nx /= x then -vx else vx
        nvy = if ny /= y then -vy else vy

fence lo hi x = max lo (min hi x)

draw (Ball (x,y) _) = translate x y (solidCircle radius)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a well-known artifact of the algorithm you're using to integrate the movement's differential equation.

The "real physics" is (I will only discuss the *y* component)

> ∂*y*/∂*t* = *v*(*t*)
>     ∂*v*/∂*t* = *g*

You model this by a discrete sequence of heights and velocities

> *y*<sub>*i*</sub> = *y*<sub>*i* − 1</sub> + *v*<sub>*i* − 1</sub> ⋅ Δ*t*
>     *v*<sub>*i*</sub> = *v*<sub>*i* − 1</sub> + g ⋅ Δ*t*

This sure resembles the differential equations, just written as difference quotients – but it's not the same thing (except in the limit Δ*t* → 0): in reality, the velocity itself changes during the time step, so it's not quite correct to alter the position just according the constant *v* value before that time step. Simply ignoring that complication is an approximation called [Euler's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_method), and it's known to suck rather badly.

The much more accurate standard alternative is the fourth-order [Runge-Kutta method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge-Kutta_method), give that a try.

n.m.'s points about the bouncing is also valid, though to do it really properly you should *calculate* the exact time of impact, to neither neglect too much acceleration nor get too much that actually never happened.

Comment: Of course Runge-Kutta would work nicely, the question is how to keep the simulation extremely simple, even sacrificing numerical accuracy, but keeping the obvious properties of the system like energy conservation.

Comment: As @n.m. says, I was more trying to get something looking realistic more than something really accurate. Runge-Kutta is still a good call since it is not that complicated to implement and it is reusable.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the ball hits the ground exactly in the middle of the quantum of time. In reality (or rather in the frictionless "reality") the absolute value of velocity stays the same in the beginning and in the end of the quantum, but in your model it increases.

One should handle acceleration in `bounce`.  The simplest possible way to do that is to do this:

```
move t (Ball (x,y) (vx,vy)) = Ball (x + vx*t, y + vy*t) (vx, vy)

step t world = bounce (move t world) t
bounce (Ball (x,y) (vx,vy)) t = Ball (nx,ny) (nvx, nvy) 
   ...
   nvy = if ny /= y then -vy else vy + g * t
```

The velocity won't increase during the bounce.

This is still not entirely accurate, the velocity still creeps up, but slower.

Comment: While the bouncing is indeed a problem (though the choice of integration algorithm is worse IMO), this is not a good way to tackle it. What has the gravitational acceleration to do with the bouncing? The function certainly shouldn't be called thus any more. The best way might be to pass the integrator as an _argument_ to `bounce`, but just inlining it all in `step` would also be ok.

Comment: This is a "good enough" solution for the bouncing problem if we care about realistic behavior without numerical accuracy. Still needs something like Runge-Kutta for the integration I think.